# Redirecting old .co.uk domains to the new .uk ccTLD

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What is the correct way to redirect my entire site from my old [example.co.uk](http://example.co.uk) domain to my new [example.uk](http://example.uk) domain including any sub-domains?

I.e.

- [test.example.co.uk](http://test.example.co.uk) → [test.example.uk](http://test.example.uk)
- [example.co.uk/images/pic.jpg](http://example.co.uk/images/pic.jpg) → [example.uk/images/pic.jpg](http://example.uk/images/pic.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proposed rule should work. I am answering in case you want to combine your 2 rules into one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s::%{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:on(s)|offs)::(.+?)\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%1://%2.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: +1 These are the sort of suggestions I'm looking for.
And thank you for reminding me of the NE flag

Comment: And +1 to your answer since your posted answer will also work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've come up with is the following (however I look for any better suggestions):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rule for HTTP traffic
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Rule for HTTPS traffic
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

This should replace the `.co.uk` with just `.uk` in any domain which has these `.htaccess` rules in it's web root directory.